# Trigger scroll in Opera mini

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-mobile-listview, opera-mini

How to scroll down or up to specific Y-px position in opera mini mobile browser on the page without using any 3rd libraries just pure js? Tried everything possible from scrollTo to SCrollInto View nothing works. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Opera doc](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/), below the **Unsupported DOM events** section you will find:

> As you can see, key events such as keypress and keyup are not
>   supported. Neither are touch and scroll events.

So `scroll` events are not supported in Opera Mini. See [Other References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291638/1647538)

Answer (score 2):

The scroll behavior is true as in every modern browser.

When you just open the new window/tab and don't touch screen the javascript scroll API via `window.scrollTo(x,y)` works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/xtKv7/show/) because you did't signaled the browser where do you want to scroll.

But if you init scroll event (for example swipe) when your page loading the browser will ignore javascript scroll API for example `scrollTo`. And if you will refresh the page the javascript scroll API will be not work. Because it's a good practice to return user on that page place where user was before refresh.

Also hash bookmarks can [scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/xtKv7/1/show/#bookmark) the page. If you set a `#bookmark` to the page URL, the page will scroll to bookmark until you scroll the page. And then you scroll all will be like I wrote upper: javascript scroll API will be ignored.

But there is one way to scroll in any case - [manipulate](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/xtKv7/6/show/) with hash bookmarks:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);//will not work if the user scroll the page
location.hash = '';//reset hash
setTimeout(function () {
    location.hash = 'bookmark';//will scroll to bookmark in any case
}, 1000)//remember about operamini timers limit
```

It works so because use must control the page, not it's code.

Comment: very useful comment, thank you but it doesnt resolve the main problem though, because the window.scroll doesnt work at all even without swiping, when I just load my page having in code something like `window.onload = function() { setTimeout(window.scroll(0,50),100); }` No scroll happenning :(.

Comment: My answer is about what `scrollTo` will not work like your aspect and it's normal. And my code example with `#bookmark` show how you can imitate it(it works in operamini)