# Opera Mini Jquery AJAX not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, opera, opera-mini

I have been developing a website for mobile devices. However due to some reasons, AJAX calls are not working on Opera Mini. For Example - one such request for loading more content at the end of page (70%)

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    if (processing) return false;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7) {
        processing = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/popup-loadmore-test.php",
            data: {
                entityid: $("#e").attr("data-id"),
                version: version
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            console.log("Data emitted: " + msg);
            $('#f').append(msg);
            version++;
            processing = false;
        });
    }
});
```

It is working everywhere, on desktop, on UC browser, android browser etc but not Opera Mini.

Please help if AJAX is written in some different way for Opera Mini. I have been reading a lot about the way Opera Mini renders page on browser. My user base has almost 50% opera users so thats a big problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `scroll` event in Opera Mini.

[Unsupported DOM events](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/#unsupporteddom) for Opera Mini:

- contextmenu
- dblclick
- error
- keydown
- keypress
- keyup
- mousemove
- mouseenter
- mouseleave
- mouseout
- mousewheel
- resize
- scroll
- touchcancel
- touchend
- touchmove
- touchstart

Read more [how Opera Mini works](http://www.opera.com/ru/help/mini/faq).

Answer (score 0):

as `scroll` event not supported by opera mini use button as load more and add `onClick` event to that button, opera mini support onClick event

```
<div id="loadmore" onClick="loadmore()">More</div>

function loadmore()
{
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax/popup-loadmore-test.php",
            data: {
                entityid: $("#e").attr("data-id"),
                version: version
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            console.log("Data emitted: " + msg);
            $('#f').append(msg);
            version++;
            processing = false;
        });
}
```